# Odoo 8 Module - adding a new field to the model

Tags: module, odoo

I am getting an error adding a new field to an Odoo 8 module. When I comment it out of the view, it works. When it is in, I get the following error:

ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Field `filedata` does not exist

Error context:
View `course.form`

This is my models.py file:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class Course(models.Model):
    _name = 'openacademy.course'

    name = fields.Char(string="Title", required=True)
    description = fields.Text()
    filedata = fields.Binary('File')
```

And this is an extract from my view file views/openacademy.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <openerp>
      <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="course_form_view">
           <field name="name">course.form</field>
           <field name="model">openacademy.course</field>
           <field name="arch" type="xml">
               <form string="Course Form">
                  <sheet>
                      <group>
                          <field name="name"/>
                          <field name="description"/>
                          <field name="filedata" />
                      </group>
                  </sheet>
               </form>
           </field>
       </record>
       ....
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try restarting Odoo server as the field probably hasn't been persisted yet due to the binary field misspelling. Try checking the PostgreSQL database directly using PgAdmin or Sql Workbench to check the field is correctly in place.

Regarding your view, everything seems right.

You should update your module through Odoo interface or with the '-u' option of the odoo.py command.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Hello dear add like **Binary** add in camelcase

```
filedata = fields.Binary('File')
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed that, but still get the error as:

ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Field `filedata` does not exist

Error context:
View `course.form`
[view_id: 1758, xml_id: n/a, model: openacademy.course, parent_id: n/a]" while parsing /etc/odoo/addons/openacademy/views/openacademy.xml:5,

Answer (score 1):

[binary](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#binary) field should be capitalized.

Answer (score -1):

- First of all define the field properly as said here:

  ```
  filedata = fields.Binary('File')
  ```

And then Uninstall and reinstall your module.

If the problem still occurs,

> Create a new database and try again.